# Android emulator stuck on Android logo with error: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-manifest

My problem is that Android emulator stuck on android logo and won't start up.

**logcat error :**

```
07-28 09:41:20.385 1381-1381/? E/Hyphenator: error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-und-ethi.hyb
                                         java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-und-ethi.hyb: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                             at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:455)
                                             at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:247)
                                             at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:118)
                                             at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:224)
                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:252)
                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:206)
                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:743)
                                          Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                             at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                             at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:187)
                                             at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:441)
                                             at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:247) 
                                             at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:118) 
                                             at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:224) 
                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:252) 
                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:206) 
                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:743) 
07-28 09:41:44.796 1963-1963/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No        such file or directory)
07-28 09:41:44.796 1963-1963/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-28 09:41:46.651 1983-1983/system_process E/PowerManagerService-JNI: Couldn't load power module (No such file or directory)
```

**android manifest** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest package="com.example.android.pets"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".CatalogActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".EditorActivity"
        android:label="@string/editor_activity_title_new_pet"
        android:theme="@style/EditorTheme"
        android:parentActivityName=".CatalogActivity" >
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".CatalogActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Can anyone give me a solution for this problem? Android emulator did crash while opening before, and after a shut down computer it doesn't crash any more but stuck on Android logo. I'm using Mac OS.